# QTreeWidget expanded columns

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qtreewidget

If I double-click between two headers the tree expands (or fits I don't know) columns.
How can I do that programmatically? I searched PyQt docs but I didn't find a method or a slot that can do that.

Thanks,
rubik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `QTreeWidget` inherits from `QTreeView` you can use;

```
void QTreeView::expandAll ()
```

which also happens to be a `slot`.

Comment: Sorry but I wanted to resize columns, not expand items. But I found QTreeView.resizeColumnToContents

Comment: if this is not the answer you wanted, why is it that you've marked this as the solution?